# iMessage Extension : Getting bundle nil from different target

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nsbundle, imessage-extension

I have an existing app and want to create a iMessage extension.

So I have added target iMessage Extension in in my project. Now I want to show my existing view in that extension via container view. I have added code :

```
let mainBundle = Bundle(identifier:"com.marvel.nearby")
print("MAIN_BUNDLE : \(mainBundle)") // getting nil
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: mainBundle)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MResourcesVC")
self.showViewControllerInContainerView(viewController)
```

in **Swift iMessage extension class** : **MessagesViewController.swift**

but getting nil. What should I do?

If this way is wrong what is the correct way to show viewcontroller in iMessage extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `storyboard.storyboard` file to your target:

[image]

To get the right bundle, use:

```
Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Comment: i tried to but i have to access it via bundle and i me getting bundle nil

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: one more if have installed pod also how can i use that?

Comment: 1.) If this fixed your issue, please accept the answer. 2) I did not understand " if have installed pod also how can i use that". Please take some time and affort to ask questions. Do you mean CocoaPods? If so, I do not understand the context Bundle issues vs. Pods?

Comment: actually in existing project im using sdwebache pods and it in viewcontroller i m using that and same view controller i want ot show in extension also

Comment: Check your podfile. It probably configures dependencies for your app target (`target "NameOfYourTarget do ...`). Do the same for your new extension target. If you can't make it, post a new question for this topic.

Comment: Thanxx i will check again :)